# Tensorflow 2.3 ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, tensorflow2.0

I know it has been asked before, but I have a slightly different problem:
I have Tensorflow 2.3.1 installed. I can successfully import it in my global environment, however if I create new virtual environment (venv) I will get an error when importing Tensorflow.

My question is: What do I need to include in my venv for it to work, and also how could I automate that process, if I want to setup that venv on a different machine.
Should I maybe ditch the idea of venv and switch to docker?

Here is the error Message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "E:\Tutorials\Coursera TensorFlow-in-Practice-Specialization-master\my solutions\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in
>
> from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
>
> module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
>
> module = self.
>
> system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "E:\Tutorials\Coursera TensorFlow-in-Practice-Specialization-master\my solutions\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*
>
> .py", line 41, in
>
> from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
>
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
>
> module = self.
>
> system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "E:\Tutorials\Coursera TensorFlow-in-Practice-Specialization-master\my solutions\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init*
>
> .py", line 40, in
>
> from tensorflow.python.eager import context
>
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
>
> module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "E:\Tutorials\Coursera TensorFlow-in-Practice-Specialization-master\my solutions\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in
>
> from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
>
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
>
> module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "E:\Tutorials\Coursera TensorFlow-in-Practice-Specialization-master\my solutions\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in
>
> from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
>
> module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "E:\Tutorials\Coursera TensorFlow-in-Practice-Specialization-master\my solutions\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in
>
> raise ImportError(msg)
>
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "E:\Tutorials\Coursera TensorFlow-in-Practice-Specialization-master\my solutions\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in
>
> from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
>
> module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>
> above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: Did you create venv manually or in PyCharm?

Comment: I created the venv using PyCharm.

Comment: Then it should be enough to put a tick on `Inherit global site-packages` checkbox

Comment: But than venv are useless? What if I share the project with other people. Or I am trying to use it on a different pc? Than I have to rely on previously installed packages, which is not clean.

Comment: Right, then consider using requirements.txt/setup.py/pipfile/pyproject.toml, venv are not safe to share as is since they are platform dependent

Comment: Ok, I will look into it. Thanks for the ideas.